# Plot a legend outside of the plotting area in base graphics?

Tags: r, plot, legend

As the title says: **How can I plot a legend outside the plotting area when using base graphics?**

I thought about fiddling around with `layout` and produce an empty plot to only contain the legend, but I would be interested in a way using just the base graph facilities and e.g., `par(mar = )` to get some space on the right of the plot for the legend.

---

Here an example:

```
plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 1, lty = 1, type = "o", ylim=c(-2,2))
lines(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 2, lty = 2, type="o")
legend(1,-1,c("group A", "group B"), pch = c(1,2), lty = c(1,2))
```

produces:

[image]

But as said, I would like the legend to be outside the plotting area (e.g., to the right of the graph/plot.

Comment: ...you can also hack par with dummy container for the legend, easy and quite convenient time-to-time. Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736647/adding-legend-annotate-to-rs-plot-similar-to-rs-ggplot).

Comment: @hhh The link is not working anymore. Can you update it or post an answer using this approach?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Maybe what you need is `par(xpd=TRUE)` to enable things to be drawn outside the plot region. So if you do the main plot with `bty='L'` you'll have some space on the right for a legend. Normally this would get clipped to the plot region, but do `par(xpd=TRUE)` and with a bit of adjustment you can get a legend as far right as it can go:

```
 set.seed(1) # just to get the same random numbers
 par(xpd=FALSE) # this is usually the default

 plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 1, lty = 1, type = "o", ylim=c(-2,2), bty='L')
 # this legend gets clipped:
 legend(2.8,0,c("group A", "group B"), pch = c(1,2), lty = c(1,2))

 # so turn off clipping:
 par(xpd=TRUE)
 legend(2.8,-1,c("group A", "group B"), pch = c(1,2), lty = c(1,2))
```

Comment: Note that you can pass xpd directly to legend so you don't need to worry about resetting par afterwards. Also see grconvertX & Y for a way to specify the location of the legend in a way not dependent on the limits of the data you're plotting.

Comment: as this question and answer are still very popular, `par(xpd=NA)` is even more powerful (i.e., plots to more regions).

Comment: +1. We should mention that it makes sense to have a separate `par` call right before the legend. In my plot, I used `par(new=T)` on several other occasions and simply wanted to add the the `xpd` param in the same call, which causes trouble.

Comment: Even in the second example the legend gets clipped slightly off the screen. Even if you try to resize the graph the legend box remains partially outside the screen. Is there a way to make it remain within the screen?

Comment: @numbermaniac I'm having the exact same issue. Did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 176):

No one has mentioned using negative `inset` values for `legend`. Here is an example, where the legend is to the right of the plot, aligned to the top (using keyword `"topright"`).

```
# Random data to plot:
A <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100, 20, 2), y=rnorm(100, 20, 2))
B <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100, 21, 1), y=rnorm(100, 21, 1))

# Add extra space to right of plot area; change clipping to figure
par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 8.1), xpd=TRUE)

# Plot both groups
plot(y ~ x, A, ylim=range(c(A$y, B$y)), xlim=range(c(A$x, B$x)), pch=1,
               main="Scatter plot of two groups")
points(y ~ x, B, pch=3)

# Add legend to top right, outside plot region
legend("topright", inset=c(-0.2,0), legend=c("A","B"), pch=c(1,3), title="Group")
```

The first value of `inset=c(-0.2,0)` might need adjusting based on the width of the legend.

[image: legend_right]

Comment: @Henrik no it does'nt work without xpd=TRUE. Also note that it is better to set xpd=TRUE as an argument of the legend() function.

Comment: Sometimes `xpd` must be set to `TRUE` for the negative inset to work. But sometimes not.  With the command `args.legend=list(x="bottom", horiz=TRUE, inset=-0.2)` within a `barplot(...` it doesn't seemd to need `xpd=TRUE` but with just `legend(x="bottom", horiz=TRUE, inset=-0.2)` it does seem to need `xpd=TRUE`. Any insights? I am just confused in passing my arguments?

Answer (score 39):

Another solution, besides the ones already mentioned (using `layout` or `par(xpd=TRUE)`) is to overlay your plot with a transparent plot over the entire device and then add the legend to that.

The trick is to overlay a (empty) graph over the complete plotting area and adding the legend to that. We can use the `par(fig=...)` option. First we instruct R to create a new plot over the entire plotting device:

```
par(fig=c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0), mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0), new=TRUE)
```

Setting `oma` and `mar` is needed since we want to have the interior of the plot cover the entire device. `new=TRUE` is needed to prevent R from starting a new device. We can then add the empty plot:

```
plot(0, 0, type='n', bty='n', xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
```

And we are ready to add the legend:

```
legend("bottomright", ...)
```

will add a legend to the bottom right of the device. Likewise, we can add the legend to the top or right margin. The only thing we need to ensure is that the margin of the original plot is large enough to accomodate the legend.

Putting all this into a function;

```
add_legend <- function(...) {
  opar <- par(fig=c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
    mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0), new=TRUE)
  on.exit(par(opar))
  plot(0, 0, type='n', bty='n', xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
  legend(...)
}
```

And an example. First create the plot making sure we have enough space at the bottom to add the legend:

```
par(mar = c(5, 4, 1.4, 0.2))
plot(rnorm(50), rnorm(50), col=c("steelblue", "indianred"), pch=20)
```

Then add the legend

```
add_legend("topright", legend=c("Foo", "Bar"), pch=20, 
   col=c("steelblue", "indianred"),
   horiz=TRUE, bty='n', cex=0.8)
```

Resulting in:

[image: Example figure shown legend in top margin]

Comment: Great addition to the list here. There's an explanation about how to make this work with multiple plots in the graphic [here](http://dr-k-lo.blogspot.com/2014/03/the-simplest-way-to-plot-legend-outside.html).

Comment: Jan, is there a way to increase the font size in the legend, without some text being clipped? For example, I have a graphic 4 different types of labels, but with a lot of empty space between them.

Comment: I've written a question with more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707308/r-using-an-answer-from-legend-outside-the-plot-in-r-but-it-still-has-some-p

Answer (score 19):

I like to do it like this:

```
par(oma=c(0, 0, 0, 5))
plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch=1, lty=1, type="o", ylim=c(-2,2))
lines(1:3, rnorm(3), pch=2, lty=2, type="o")
legend(par('usr')[2], par('usr')[4], bty='n', xpd=NA,
       c("group A", "group B"), pch=c(1, 2), lty=c(1,2))
```

[image]

The only tweaking required is in setting the right margin to be wide enough to accommodate the legend.

However, this can also be automated:

```
dev.off() # to reset the graphics pars to defaults
par(mar=c(par('mar')[1:3], 0)) # optional, removes extraneous right inner margin space
plot.new()
l <- legend(0, 0, bty='n', c("group A", "group B"), 
            plot=FALSE, pch=c(1, 2), lty=c(1, 2))
# calculate right margin width in ndc
w <- grconvertX(l$rect$w, to='ndc') - grconvertX(0, to='ndc')
par(omd=c(0, 1-w, 0, 1))
plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch=1, lty=1, type="o", ylim=c(-2, 2))
lines(1:3, rnorm(3), pch=2, lty=2, type="o")
legend(par('usr')[2], par('usr')[4], bty='n', xpd=NA,
       c("group A", "group B"), pch=c(1, 2), lty=c(1, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Using xpd=T or xpd=NA doesn't prevent my 'main' (title) from being clipped when it is stretched to try to use the area added with the wide right margin.

Comment: @PhilGoetz are you sure you're plotting main within the plot area? Is it possible that you don't have enough lines of margin there to plot in?

Answer (score 18):

Sorry for resurrecting an old thread, but I was with the same problem today. The simplest way that I have found is the following:

```
# Expand right side of clipping rect to make room for the legend
par(xpd=T, mar=par()$mar+c(0,0,0,6))

# Plot graph normally
plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 1, lty = 1, type = "o", ylim=c(-2,2))
lines(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 2, lty = 2, type="o")

# Plot legend where you want
legend(3.2,1,c("group A", "group B"), pch = c(1,2), lty = c(1,2))

# Restore default clipping rect
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
```

Found here: http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/R/

Comment: Even better is

  oldpar <- par(xpd=T, mar=par()$mar+c(0,0,0,6))
  ...
  par(oldpar)

(See the help of par)

Comment: This solution is better because the space for legend is fixed not matter the length of strings of legend

Answer (score 13):

Adding another simple alternative that is quite elegant in my opinion.

Your plot:

```
plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 1, lty = 1, type = "o", ylim=c(-2,2))
lines(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 2, lty = 2, type="o")
```

Legend:

```
legend("bottomright", c("group A", "group B"), pch=c(1,2), lty=c(1,2),
       inset=c(0,1), xpd=TRUE, horiz=TRUE, bty="n"
       )
```

Result:

[image: picture with legend]

Here only the second line of the legend was added to your example. In turn:

- `inset=c(0,1)` - moves the legend by fraction of plot region in (x,y) directions. In this case the legend is at `"bottomright"` position. It is moved by 0 plotting regions in x direction (so stays at "right") and by 1 plotting region in y direction (from bottom to top). And it so happens that it appears right above the plot.
- `xpd=TRUE` - let's the legend appear outside of plotting region.
- `horiz=TRUE` - instructs to produce a horizontal legend.
- `bty="n"` - a style detail to get rid of legend bounding box.

Same applies when adding legend to the side:

```
par(mar=c(5,4,2,6))
plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 1, lty = 1, type = "o", ylim=c(-2,2))
lines(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 2, lty = 2, type="o")

legend("topleft", c("group A", "group B"), pch=c(1,2), lty=c(1,2),
       inset=c(1,0), xpd=TRUE, bty="n"
       )
```

Here we simply adjusted legend positions and added additional margin space to the right side of the plot. Result:

[image: picture with legend 2]

Comment: Tried this and it works. Much simpler.

Answer (score 10):

I can offer only an example of the layout solution already pointed out.

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow = 1), widths = c(0.7, 0.3))
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 1, lty = 1, type = "o", ylim=c(-2,2))
lines(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 2, lty = 2, type="o")
par(mar = c(5, 0, 4, 2) + 0.1)
plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 1, lty = 1, ylim=c(-2,2), type = "n", axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE)
legend(1, 1, c("group A", "group B"), pch = c(1,2), lty = c(1,2))
```

[image: an ugly picture :S]

Answer (score 10):

Recently I found very easy and interesting function to print legend outside of the plot area where you want.

Make the outer margin at the right side of the plot.

```
par(xpd=T, mar=par()$mar+c(0,0,0,5))
```

Create a plot

```
plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 1, lty = 1, type = "o", ylim=c(-2,2))
lines(1:3, rnorm(3), pch = 2, lty = 2, type="o")
```

Add legend and just use locator(1) function as like below. Then you have to just click where you want after load following script.

```
legend(locator(1),c("group A", "group B"), pch = c(1,2), lty = c(1,2))
```

Try it

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with the [Plotly R API](https://plot.ly/api/r), with either code, or from the GUI by dragging the legend where you want it.

Here is an example. The graph and code are also [here](https://plot.ly/api/r-project/docs/legends).

```
x = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) 
y = c(0,3,6,4,5,2,3,5,4) 
x2 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) 
y2 = c(0,4,7,8,3,6,3,3,4)
```

You can position the legend outside of the graph by assigning one of the x and y values to either 100 or -100.

```
legendstyle = list("x"=100, "y"=1)
layoutstyle = list(legend=legendstyle)
```

Here are the other options:

- `list("x" = 100, "y" = 0)` for Outside Right Bottom
- `list("x" = 100, "y"= 1)` Outside Right Top
- `list("x" = 100, "y" = .5)` Outside Right Middle
- `list("x" = 0, "y" = -100)` Under Left
- `list("x" = 0.5, "y" = -100)` Under Center
- `list("x" = 1, "y" = -100)` Under Right

Then the response.

`response = p$plotly(x,y,x2,y2, kwargs=list(layout=layoutstyle));`

Plotly returns a URL with your graph when you make a call. You can access that more quickly by calling `browseURL(response$url)` so it will open your graph in your browser for you.

```
url = response$url
filename = response$filename
```

That gives us this graph. You can also move the legend from within the GUI and then the graph will scale accordingly. Full disclosure: I'm on the Plotly team.

[image: Legend on side of graph]

Answer (score 3):

Try `layout()` which I have used for this in the past by  simply creating an empty plot below, properly scaled at around 1/4 or so and placing the legend parts manually in it.

There are some older questions here about `legend()` which should get you started.

Comment: As already said in the question, this is what I thought about, too. But it would be ideal, if there would be another way. Somehow I suppose there isn't.