# Plot points outside plotting region in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to add points(asterisks) outside the plotting region of a plot in R. However, the following code only allows points to be added inside the plotting region:

```
x = c(1:10)
y = c(1:10)
plot(x,y)
points(11, 7, pch = 8)
```

How can I adjust code to allow the point to be plotted outside the plotting region?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics) SO post might help! It's about legends, but you can probably apply the same method for what you want.

This worked for me:

```
> par(xpd=TRUE)
> x = c(1:10)
> y = c(1:10)
> plot(x,y)
> points(11, 7, pch = 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
plot(1:10, 1:10)
par(new = TRUE, mar = c(0,0,0,0))
plot(1:10, 1:10, xaxt = 'n',yaxt='n')
```