# using grid to annotate lattice plots outside of the plotting region

Tags: r, lattice, clipping, r-grid

I often use the lattice package to create figures. I then use `grid::grid.text()` to annotate the figures outside of the plotting region. Typically, I make PDF files, and there are no problems.

I now need to save my figures in other formats, like PNG. And I now find that when I try to annotate outside of the plotting region, the annotations are clipped. Here is a small example:

```r
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(lattice)

myPanel <- function (...) { 
  panel.xyplot(...)
  grid.text("This is a very, very long line", x = .99, y = .5)
}
xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10, panel = myPanel, par.settings = list(clip = list(panel="off")))
```

[image]

I can get around this problem by using `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`, but it seems like a too-elaborate way to solve a simple problem:

```
myPlot_grob     <- grid.grab(wrap = TRUE)
rectTransparent <- rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = 'transparent', fill = 'transparent'))
grid.arrange(
  grobs = list(
    rectTransparent,
    myPlot_grob,
    rectTransparent),
  ncol = 3,
  widths = unit(c(2, 4, 2), 'inches'))
```

[image]

Is there a simpler way? I have both Deepayan Sarkar's book on lattice and Paul Murrell's *R Graphics,* but I haven't found a clear solution in them. There are related SO posts for the problem when it comes up in [base graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417269/plot-points-outside-plotting-region-in-r) or [ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409960/ggplot2-annotate-outside-of-plot), but I haven't found posts that speak to the issue in lattice graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually adjust the margin padding.

```
lattice.options(layout.widths=list(left.padding=list(x=0), right.padding=list(x=5)))

xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10, panel = myPanel, par.settings = list(clip = list(panel="off")))
```

[image]

But since it has to be done manually, it may not be an ideal solution.

Comment: Thank you - that does help. I had tried to do something similar with `trellis.par.set()`, and it didn't work. But I hadn't thought about `lattice.options()`.  //  There is a tradeoff between `left.padding` and `right.padding` that I don't understand: increasing one seems to decrease the other, even if the value for the other that's specified in `lattice.options` doesn't change. But I can work around that problem.