# How to do I label my y axis, and make a simple graph look good in r?

Tags: r, plot, axis

Hi i have to make a simple graph using r, but I would like to make it look good, I am also having some trouble labeling my y axis, what I've written so far is this:

```
anim <- c(1.72,1.6,1.7,1.74,1.8)
mirr <- c(.80,.95,1.13,1.17,1.26)
g_range <- range(0.8, anim, mirr)
plot(anim, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range, axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
axis(1, at=1:5, lab=c(".5", ".6", ".7", ".8", ".9"))
axis(2, las=2, at=0:g_range[2])
axis(2)
box()
lines(mirr, type="o", pch=22, lty=2, col="red")
title(main="corr vs dprime", col.main="forestgreen", font.main=4)
title(xlab="Correlation", col.lab="black", font.main=4)
title(ylab="dprime", col.lab="black", font.main=4)
legend(1, g_range[2], c("anim", "mirr"), cex=0.8,
col=c("blue","red"), pch=21:22, lty=1:2);
```

which gives this graph:

[image]

I can't figure out how to make the graph area big enough to comfortably fit the legend in, and how to correctly label my y axis, I have no idea where the sideways 1 has come from? r newbie so any help would be great!

Comment: you could use `ylim=g_range + c(0, .2)` instead of what you have now. there are two y-axes because you are doing `axis(2, ...)` twice

Comment: Move your legend down. See `?legend`. Use the x and y parameters. To change the orientation of axis tick labels read the help page for ?par (and find the 'las'-parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose to stay with the `base` plotting functions in R, you can address each of your concerns. The following response is simply meant to review and illustrate previous comments from this question and include other SO-related materials for additional assistance.

First, let's tackle the y-axis issue. As suggested in the original comments, you are currently calling the `axis` command twice with respect to the y-axis. By identifying your desired y-axis limits early on, they can be easily applied with the `ylim` argument.

```
df<-data.frame(anim=c(1.72,1.6,1.7,1.74,1.8),mirr=c(.80,.95,1.13,1.17,1.26))
gmin<-min(df) #<---- ESTABLISH MIN Y-AXIS VALUE
gmax<-max(df) #<---- ESTABLISH MAX Y-AXIS VALUE
plot(df$anim,type="o",col="blue",ylim=c(gmin,gmax),axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE)
box()
axis(1,at=1:5,lab=seq(0.5,0.9,0.1))
axis(2,seq(gmin,gmax,0.2),las=2)
lines(df$mirr,type="o",pch=22,lty=2,col="red")
title(main="corr vs dprime",col.main="forestgreen",font.main=4)
title(xlab="Correlation",col.lab="black",font.main=4)
title(ylab="dprime",col.lab="black",font.main=4)
```

[image: Image 1]

Second, the legend can be placed either within the plotting area or placed outside. As suggested in the original comments, type in `?legend` and review the `x, y` arguments for positioning your legend. This would likely be your best approach since your range of x and y values are small, which would allow for easy legend placement. Although less specific, you can also use keywords to specify the legend's position (`?legend` under Details) such as "bottomright", "bottom", "bottomleft", "left", "topleft", "top", "topright", "right" and "center". For instance:

```
legend('bottomright', c("anim", "mirr"), cex=0.8,col=c("blue","red"), pch=21:22, lty=1:2)
```

[image: Image 2 - Legend using keywords]

where adjusting arguments, such as `x.intersp`, `y.intersp`, and `cex`, will allow you to change the legend's shape and relative size.

Additionally, you can create your legend outside of the plotting area as shown by the previous answer using `ggplot2`. Several options are recommended in the following SO answer: [Plot a legend outside of the plotting area in base graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics). The most popular methods take advantage of the `xpd` argument in `par` followed by the `x, y` or `inset` arguments from `legend`.

Without adjusting margins about the plotting area, you can simply select x and y parameters so the legend is placed properly while not overlapping other items. For instance:

```
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend(4.5,2.1,c('anim','mirr'),cex=0.8,col=c('blue','red'),pch=21:22,lty=1:2)
```

[image]

where the box about the legend can be controlled using the `bty` argument in `legend`.

If you would prefer your legend more like the previous answer, you will need to review the `mai`, `mar`, and `oma` arguments in `par` so that the legend is properly displayed ([see here](http://research.stowers-institute.org/mcm/efg/R/Graphics/Basics/mar-oma/index.htm)). Once configured, you can then specify your legend's position outside of the plot area using `inset` argument in `legend`:

```
par(oma=c(0,0,0,1),mar=c(5.1,4.1, 4.1, 5.1),xpd=T)
plot(df$anim,type="o",col="blue",ylim=c(gmin,gmax),axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE)
box()
axis(1,at=1:5,lab=seq(0.5,0.9,0.1))
axis(2,seq(gmin,gmax,0.2),las=2)
lines(df$mirr,type="o",pch=22,lty=2,col="red")
title(main="corr vs dprime",col.main="forestgreen",font.main=4)
title(xlab="Correlation",col.lab="black",font.main=4)
title(ylab="dprime",col.lab="black",font.main=4)
legend('right',inset=c(-0.4,0),c('anim','mirr'),cex=0.8,col=c('blue','red'),pch=21:22,lty=1:2)
```

[image]

Alongside other answers, I hope this small review helps your current situation and demonstrates R's flexibility using `base` and other plotting functions. Credit goes to previous users and their comments along with the other SO answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `ggplot2`:

```
anim <- c(1.72,1.6,1.7,1.74,1.8)
mirr <- c(.80,.95,1.13,1.17,1.26)

df <- data.frame(
dprime = c(anim, mirr),
correlation = rep(seq(.5,.9,.1), 2),
group = rep(c("anim", "mirr"), each=5)
)
# Uncomment if you don't have ggplot2 installed
# install.packages("ggplot2")

library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(correlation, dprime, color=group)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Corr vs. Dprime")
g
```

[image]