# adjust a legend position in a barplot

Tags: r, plot

I need to adjust the legend for the following barplot in a proper position somewhere outside the plot

```
COLORS=rainbow(18)
barplot(sort(task3_result$respondents_share,decreasing = TRUE), main="Share of respondents that mentioned brand among top 3 choices ", names.arg=task3_result$brand, col = COLORS)
legend("right", tolower(as.character(task3_result$brand)), yjust=1,col = COLORS, lty=c(1,1) )
```

[image]

Comment: Please give a reproducible example

Comment: have you tried "topright" instead of "right"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys, i couldn't solve the problem but i reached my goal using ggplot,

```
windows(width = 500, height= 700)
ggplot(data = task3_result, aes(x = factor(brand), y = respondents_share, fill = brand)) + 
geom_bar(colour = 'black', stat = 'identity') + scale_fill_discrete(name = 'brands') + coord_flip()+
ggtitle('Share of respondents that mentioned brand among top 3 choices') +xlab("Brands") + ylab("Share of respondents")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As DatamineR pointed out, your code is not reproducible as-is (we don't have `task3_result`), but you can probably accomplish what you're talking about by playing with the `x` and `y` arguments to `legend()` - you can just set the `x` coordinate to something beyond the edges of the bars, for example. See the documentation: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/legend.html. Also note there the `cex` argument, because that legend might be bulkier than you want.

Note that you will have to specify a larger plot window in order to leave space for the legend; the relevant help file for that is `plot.window`: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.window.html

Though you won't want to call `plot.window` directly - better to pass the relevant arguments to it through the `barplot()` function. If that doesn't make sense, I recommend you read up on R's base plotting package more generally.