# Add a legend to a google map obtained with dismo gmap R

Tags: r, plot, legend, raster

```
[![require(raster)
require(dismo)

oc_go<-gmap(extent(c(10042219 ,19646634,-7110934,1881964)),type='terrain')
plot(oc_go)
```

... add another layer

```
legend("bottom", legend = c(" 1", " 2"," 3"," 4"," 5"," 6"," 7"," 8"), fill = colvec, 
       cex = 0.7, inset = 0.9,xpd=T,horiz = T)
```

The  result is

[image]

I would like to put the legend on the bottom or outside of the plotting area.

Using par() like this

```
par(xpd = FALSE,mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.5))
plot(oc_go)
par(xpd = TRUE)
legend(par()$usr[2] ,-1000000, legend = c(" 1", " 2"," 3"," 4"," 5"," 6"," 7"," 8"), fill = colvec, 
       cex = 0.7, inset = 0.9)
```

doesn't seem to work very well with the map downloaded with gmap(). I tried also overlying the plot area as described in answer 3 here [Plot a legend outside of the plotting area in base graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics)