# how to place legend horizontaly above barplot in r

Tags: r

I have to place my legend horizontally above the barplot. I have search a lot but could not found a statisfactory answer. I have found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics) but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "horizontally" ? are you looking for `ncol` parameter ? Please provide a [mcve] and expected output

Comment: I think below answer is what I am looking for. Please upvote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what your data looks like and what you want your legend to be but horizontal legends are produced by setting `horiz = TRUE`. You can place a legend on the top of a plot using `"top"` as the legend position. If you want it outside your plot region you can move it upward using `inset` (you'll have to play around with the value a bit) and setting `xpd = TRUE` (which basically allows you to write outside the plot region):

Example:

```
barplot(c(10,2,7), col = 1:3) 
legend("top", fill = 1:3, legend = c("A", "B", "C"), 
    horiz = TRUE, inset = c(0,-0.1), xpd = TRUE)
```

produces the following graph:

barplot with horizontal legend on top

[image]