# Exact position of legend above R plot

Tags: r, plot, position, margin, legend

I want to produce a simple plot with a legend on the top right above the plot (see picture below, plot on the left). I can achieve this by using the following simple example:

```
par(mar = c(4, 4, 1.5, 4))
plot(rnorm(50))
par(oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0), mar = c(0, 0, 0, 4), new = TRUE)
plot(0, 0, type = "n", bty = "n", axes = F)
legend(x = "topright", "data", bty = "n", pch = 1, xpd = T, horiz = T)
```

When I scale this plot to different sizes the legend sometimes overlaps the plot area though (plot on the right).
[image: Plot in different sizes. Note the legend overlapping the plot area on the right side of the figure.]

How can I achieve no overlapping legend for varying plot sizes (or width/height ratios)? I would highly appreciate help on this problem!

Comment: Try this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics.

Comment: `legend` does not play well with resizing window after plotting. It's better to define the plot size before using `pdf` or `windows`

Comment: Oh, so defining the plot size eliminates the problem, since the "line width" for the margins will be fixed? That works for me, since I want to define a specific size anyway. Thanks for the help!