# determine the position of a legend in R, so legend does not overlap the piecharts

Tags: r, plot, legend

I need to have these two piecharts and the legend in the middle, how can I determine the position of a legend to be exactly in the middle, so it will not overlap the piecharts.

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2)) 
pie(frman, main="Men", col=cols, labels=pielabelsman, cex=0.85)
pie(frwoman, main="Women", col=cols,labels=pielabelswoman,cex=0.85)
legend("center", uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can place the legend in different places by default commands:

```
legend("center", uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)    
legend("bottomright", uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)
legend("bottom", uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)
legend("bottomleft", uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)
legend("left", uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)
legend("topleft", uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)
legend("top", uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)
legend("topright", uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)
legend("right", uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)
legend("center", uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)
```

Otherwise you can specify it yourself by inputting the x and y coordinates, for instance:

```
legend(x = 2, y = 5 , uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)
```

You can find more information [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/legend.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics), [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/add-legends-to-plots-in-r-software-the-easiest-way) or [here](http://dr-k-lo.blogspot.nl/2014/03/the-simplest-way-to-plot-legend-outside.html), just to give some examples.

**UPDATE**

You can also try with:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), heights=c(4, 1))
par(mai=rep(0.5, 4)) 
pie(frman, main="Men", col=cols, labels=pielabelsman, cex=0.85)
pie(frwoman, main="Women", col=cols,labels=pielabelswoman,cex=0.85)
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
legend("center", uniq, cex=0.5,fill=cols)
```

As I don't have your data I can't check whether it looks right or not, but I think it should.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried your last line with different x and y values but I can not find the appropriate x,y to observe the legend.

Comment: the thing is that I am using par(mfrow = c(1,2)), so x,y corresponds to one of the two plots each time

Comment: @GiorgosVoultsios I updated the answer. Don't forget to upvote and accept answer if it works! Thanks!