# Putting a legend not to overlap a histogram in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram, legend, distribution

I would like to put legends in my histogram without overlapping lines.
I am going to show my R codes, and the histogram.

```
#Installing 'readxl' to load a xlsx file    
install.packages("readxl")
library(readxl)

#Loading xlsx file
value <- read_excel("C:/Users/user/Desktop/value.xlsx")

#Setting 'graph' vector
graph <- hist(value$value)

#Calculating 'frequency percentage'
graph$density <- graph$counts / sum(graph$counts) * 100

#Drawing a histogram
plot(graph, main = "Title", xlab = "x-axis", ylab = "Frequency(%)", ylim = c(0, 100), breaks = "Sturges", col = "Gray", freq = FALSE, xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = seq(-8, 8, by =2))

#Plotting a frequency(%) polygon on the histogram(I have no idea how to draw smooth curve; thus, I used 'line() function')
lines(x = graph$mids, y =graph$density, type = "l", lty = 6, col = "Red")

#Putting a legend on the topright of the graph
legend("topright", c("The distribution of frequency(%)", "mean", "±2SD"), col = c("Red", "Black", "Black"), lty = c(6, 1, 2), lwd = c(2, 1, 1))

#Computing mean and standard deviations
m <- mean(value$value)
std <- sd(value$value)

#Plotting mean and ±2SD values
abline(v = m, lty = 1)
abline(v = m + 2*std, lty = 2)
abline(v = m - 2*std, lty = 2)
```

By the way, the legend is overlapped on the histogram. This is the picture of the result of the R codes.
[image]

Could I put legends another area, which is not overlapped with the graph?
I need your help, and thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you want the legend to appear. Here is one example where it's on the right side of the title:

```
value <- rnorm(1000)
graph <- hist(value, breaks="Sturges", main = "Title", xlab = "x-axis", ylab = "Frequency(%)", col = "Gray", freq = FALSE, xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = seq(-8, 8, by =2))

#Plotting a frequency(%) polygon on the histogram(I have no idea how to draw smooth curve; thus, I used 'line() function')
lines(x = graph$mids, y = graph$density, type = "l", lty = 6, col = "Red")

#Putting a legend on the topright of the graph
legend("bottomright", c("The distribution of frequency(%)", "mean", "±2SD"),
       col = c("Red", "Black", "Black"), lty = c(6, 1, 2), lwd = c(2, 1, 1),
       xpd=TRUE, inset=c(0,1), cex=0.7, bty='n'
       )

#Computing mean and standard deviations
m   <- mean(value)
std <- sd(value)

#Plotting mean and ±2SD values
abline(v = m + c(0, 2*std, -2*std), lty=c(1,2,2))
```

Note that I only added `xpd`, `inset`, `cex` and `bty` parameters to the legend. first two are most important: `xpd` allows you to plot the legend outside the plotting region in the margins and `inset` controls the adjustment of legend position. You can learn more about these in `help(legend)`.

Here is the resulting plot:

[image: barplot with legend]

You can see more examples and explanations here: [Plot a legend outside of the plotting area in base graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3932038/1953718)