# Plotting legend outside plot in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I am trying to put the legend outside the plot using `xpd=TRUE` but the legend keeps plotting within the plot. How can I fix this?

```
x = c(0,0,1,1,1)
y = c(0.4991,1.1423,1.2258,1.158,0.5148)
dat<-cbind(x,y)
point_shape = c(10,15,10,15,1)
dat<-data.frame(x,y,point_shape)

myTicks<-c(0,1)
plot(dat[,1],dat[,2], yaxt="n", xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="",pch = dat$point_shape)
abline(0.4991,0.7267)
abline(1.1423,0.0157)
abline(0.4991,0.0157,lty=2)
axis(side = 1, at = myTicks)
axis(side = 2, at = myTicks)


legend("bottomleft", legend = c("apple", "orange", "tree"),
       bty = "n", xpd=FALSE, mar(c(7,7,7,7)), cex = 1, pch = c(10, 15, 1))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot a legend outside of the plotting area in base graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the help for `legend`:

> The location may also be specified by setting x to a single keyword
>   from the list "bottomright", "bottom", "bottomleft", "left",
>   "topleft", "top", "topright", "right" and "center". This places the
>   legend on the inside of the plot frame at the given location.

So you can place the legend outside the plotting region by giving its coordinates manually:

```
legend(-0.2, 0.3, legend = c("apple", "orange", "tree"),
       bty = "n", xpd=TRUE, mar=c(7,7,7,7), cex = 1, pch = c(10, 15, 1))
```

Answer (score 9):

Use inset and make xpd to true

```
legend("bottomleft", legend = c("apple", "orange", "tree"), inset=c(-0.15,0),
   bty = "n", xpd=TRUE, mar(c(7,7,7,7)), cex = 1, pch = c(10, 15, 1))
```