# hidden plot legend in r

Tags: r, plot

I have a problem with the external legend of a plot:
here's the code:

```
x1<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\...\\x1.csv",sep=";")

plot(b~obs,data=x1,xlab="Observations",ylab="values", xlim=c(1,13), ylim=c(1,13),pch=1,cex=1)

points(x1$a,pch=20,cex=1)
```

For the legend I've tried this:

```
legend( x=15,y=10, xpd=TRUE, xjust=0, yjust=.5,
    legend=c("w/o FU", "w FU"),
    pch=c(1,20),cex=1)
```

and this:

```
legend( x="topleft",inset=c(1,0), xpd=TRUE,bty="n", 
    legend=c("w/o FU", "w FU"),
    pch=c(1,20),cex=1)
```

and this is what I obtain:
[image]

The legend is hidded and I can't view it nor zooming neither expanding the window.

How can I fix it

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read the answers to this question? I'm pretty sure you can find your solution there:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics?rq=1

Comment: Yup, ArTu it will likely be a `par(mar=...)` thing.

Comment: @divibisan of course I did but I can find how to put The legend outside the plot but not why I have the legend cut

Comment: @r2evans what do you mean? I should use par to have more space even if I have only 1 plot?

Comment: `par` sets many parameters for base R graphics, not just multiple plots. The `mar` and `mai` parameters set margin size. `?par` has a full listing of the graphical parameters you can change

Comment: From [`?par`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/par.html): *A numerical vector of the form 'c(bottom, left, top, right)' which gives the number of lines of margin to be specified on the four sides of the plot.  The default is 'c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1'.*

Comment: Thank you! I'll study the mar and mai parameters!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plot(mpg~disp, data=mtcars)
legend(par("usr")[2], par("usr")[4], legend=c("Abc","Xyz"),pch=c(1,20), inset=c(0,0), xpd=TRUE)
```

[image: bad margins]

```
par(mar=c(5,4,4,4)+0.1) # default is c(5,4,4,2)+0.1
plot(mpg~disp, data=mtcars)
legend(par("usr")[2], par("usr")[4], legend=c("Abc","Xyz"),pch=c(1,20), inset=c(0,0), xpd=TRUE)
```

[image: shifted margin]