# Why can't I move my legend for my bargraph in R?

Tags: r, graph

my very sad bargraph

[image]

```
legend("topright", c("No Response", "Correct", "Incorrect"), 
        fill=c("#999999", "#33FF33", "#FF0000"))
legend("bottomright", c("No Response", "Correct", "Incorrect"), 
       fill=c("#999999", "#33FF33", "#FF0000"))
```

When I try to make it smaller I use `cex=0.75`, but all that does is make the legend smaller, it still sits on top of the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot a legend outside of the plotting area in base graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics)

Comment: Thank you for your help!! I got it to work!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Base graphics doesn't naturally make room for legends and such (perhaps because it does not know you're planning on adding one). You can use `xlim` (and/or `ylim`) of the original plot in order to make room for it.

```r
barplot(GNP ~ Year, data = longley)
legend("bottomright", c("No Response", "Correct", "Incorrect"), 
       fill=c("#999999", "#33FF33", "#FF0000"))
```

[image: barplot, legend overlaid on data]

```r
par("usr")[1:2]
# [1] -0.56 19.96
barplot(GNP ~ Year, data = longley, xlim = c(0, 26))
legend("bottomright", c("No Response", "Correct", "Incorrect"), 
       fill=c("#999999", "#33FF33", "#FF0000"))
```

[image: barplot, legend placed better]