# Avoid overlapping legend with axis label

Tags: r, plot, legend

When I try to add the legend to the bottom center, it overlaps with the y axis label.

Here is an image of the plot for reference:

[image: 1]

And my code:

```
legend('center',
       'groups',
       lty=1,
       col=c("red","gold","blue","green","black","purple","orange","pink","grey","dark blue","violet","dark red","brown","maroon"),
       legend=c("Babl","Chli","Cuaz","Frve","Juma","Pafl","Pibr","Pich","Plwr","Prgl","Quvi","Sela","Ulpa","Vaca"),
       bty="n",
       xpd = TRUE,
       ncol=3)
```

Comment: Please add more code of your legend. As is - it's plotted at the center of the image. Maybe you are missing some additional line you called before calling `legend()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot a legend outside of the plotting area in base graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics)

Comment: i'm not sure anyone actually read the question.. when you make your plot, just omit the xlab (`xlab = '')` and adjust the position after the plot `title(xlab = ..., line = 4)` until it is not overlapping with the legend. you may need to increase the margins of the plot first `par(mar = c(8, 5, 2, 1))` etc to have more space for both the legend and the xlab

Answer (score 1):

In your legend, you specify that you want your legend to be in the center. You can change the position by replacing `"center"` with `"bottomright"`, `"bottom"`, `"bottomleft"`, `"left"`, `"topleft"`, `"top"`, `"topright"`, and `"right"`.